# Print dec values to printer in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, winapi, printing

I am new to Access VBA but not to programming. I have created a simple Microsoft Access application that mimics a cash register.  All seems to work well.  My last hurdle is to send decimal characters to a thermal printer that will open the cash drawer.

I have tried a VBA printer object but that does not seem to work.

Cannot find a good win32api example.  Although win32api will probably be the final solution.

I need to send decimal codes of 27, 112, 0, 127, 127.  Printer name is "EOM-200 V1.2"

Thanks in advance.

JED

```
Dim hexCode As String
  
Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers("EOM-200 V1.2")
  
Open Application.Printer.Port For Output As #1
  
hexCode = Chr(27) & Chr(112) & Chr(0) & Chr(127) & Chr(127)
      
Print #1, hexCode
  
Close #1
    
Set Application.Printer = Nothing
```

Code above did nothing

Comment: Is this relevent? See the posts about "line mode driver". https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/32753-send-esc-command-to-thermal-printer/

Comment: Have you checked that `Application.Printer.Port` returns something (and the correct port)? E.g. "LPT1" or "COM1" or "USB002".

Answer (score -1):

It could be Unicode that messes up `hexCode`. Try:

```vb
Print #1, StrConv(hexcode, vbFromUnicode)

' or:

Print #1, ChrB(29) & ChrB(107) & ChrB(72) & ChrB(12)
```

Comment: I would think that there are easier ways of generating the character sequence to send to the thermal printer than VBA as VBA will be too helpful if it can for instance using a text file and "printing" it. Using `ChrB` instead of `Chr` looks promising though.